# PHP email form won't submit with different entered email address

Tags: php, forms, email

Any idea why the [Enter email] field on this form will only reach me@me.com if the email entered matches me@me.com?

If I put in any other email address than the one listed in $to=, the email doesn't send.

```
$fieldname = 'images';
    if ($_POST){

    // we'll begin by assigning the To address and message subject
    $to="me@me.com";
    $subject="Registration";

    $from = "<".stripslashes($_POST['email']).">";

// generate a random string to be used as the boundary marker
$mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

// now we'll build the message headers
$headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
           "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
           "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
           " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"\n";
```

Here's a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3YTZZssM).

Comment: It probably sends but is flagged as spam

Comment: I worked that out with the hosting provider and created a subdomain for the email address, which they tested and it works fine. Also, no messages are in spam.

Comment: You might want to pass the complete code, including where the e-mail is sent by PHP.

Comment: Where's the code to send the mail? the SMTP protocol requires `MAIL FROM` and an `RCPT TO` commands - the headers are part of the `DATA` command.

Comment: @pivemi Will do. The form is very long so will have to strip lines but will get that up asap, thanks

Comment: @bunnycode - it's possible that one of the intermediate servers decides that the email is spam, and just deletes it; so it doesn't ever arrive.

Comment: Not sure why that would happen. I'm not actually using me@me.com, I just didn't want to post the business's email address or my email address. me@me.com was an example. If the website is websiteurl.com, the email address is info@websiteurl.com

Comment: @Kenney Here it is http://pastebin.com/3YTZZssM

Comment: Thanks. These days, it's getting harder to spoof sender addresses because of things like DKIM and SPF. It's likely you're using a 3rd party mail server that refuses to accept such mails. You're better off using a `mysite@me.com` sender address and perhaps add a `Reply-To` header with the original sender.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the *from* header to be the address posted in the form, and the *to* header to be your email address. Should be reversed if you are trying to send an email to them.

```
$to="me@me.com";
$subject="Registration";

$from = "<".stripslashes($_POST['email']).">";
```

If indeed you want the email to appear to come from the address listed in the form, you can't in general do that. You can't send email on behalf of another use (your SMTP server is likely to reject it these days). This is to prevent pfishing attacks (FROM: Someone@ThatYouKnow.com, SUBJECT: What is that password again?).

Send it from an email address that you control. Include the email address from the form as part of the body of the email.

Comment: This sends the email to the email address that is entered into the form. That's not what I want. I was unclear, apologies. I want the form to go to businessA@email.com... and the user needs to provide *their* email address when they fill out the form. And the email needs to go to businessA@email.com

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and works just fine. Thank you very very much!